# How to get the public IP of my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get the public IP address of my AWS EC2 instance using Go.

```
func getIpAdrress(svc *session.Session) {
    result, err := svc.DescribeAddresses(&ec2.DescribeAddressesInput{
        Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
            {
                Name:   aws.String("TeamSpeakServer"),
                Values: aws.StringSlice([]string{"vpc"}),
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to elastic IP address, %v", err)
    }

    // Printout the IP addresses if there are any.
    if len(result.Addresses) == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("No elastic IPs for %s region\n", *svc.Config.Region)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Elastic IPs")
        for _, addr := range result.Addresses {
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to get the IP address and the instance that are running, or maybe pass a machine id to get the IP, but I have been looking at AWS docs all day and this is what i have so far.
This is the error I get:

> svc.DescribeAddresses undefined (type *session.Session has no field or method DescribeAddresses)

Comment: The normal method would be to [Retrieve instance metadata - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) by making an HTTP request to `169.254.169.254`.

Comment: hi thank you for you help but i really need to do using the sdk as part of the open session .

Comment: You can just get the results of `https://checkip.amazonaws.com/`

Comment: that give me the address of AWS not the public address of the instance im running . maybe I'm misunderstanding,

Comment: I believe the confusion is because you haven't stated if your code is running on the EC2 instance itself, or somewhere else. The comments you are getting would work on the EC2 instance itself, if the code on the instance needs to know its own public IP address. If not, then what you are doing already is the correct method.

Comment: ok no problem i found a way below anyway. i am new to AWS and the go SDK so thank you for taking the time to answer my question its very kind of you . i will also keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

```
func getDetaislOFAnInstance(sess *session.Session) {

    ec2Svc := ec2.New(sess)
    result, err := ec2Svc.DescribeInstances(nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success", result)
    }

}
```

Comment: if anyone knows a better way so i don't have to parse the JSON that would be awesome